# How to disable or skip the payment method step in checkout process in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-2.3

I have magento Open Source 2.3.2 setup my client don't want any payment method now. How to remove payment method step in checkout process. I just want to place order without selection payment method.

Preferably, answer with the exact code and folder structure.

Below is the exact representation of the requirement.
[image]

Comment: I think you have to create custom payment method and when order place pass this payment method in it